# Update array in nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection defined as bellow.

```
const aclSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userId: Number,
  resourcePermissions: [{
    resource: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    permissions: [String],
  }],
});
```

I want to update or remove specific access on resource, where role matches.
So, this is the data currently.

```
[{
    "role": "ops",
    "resourcePermissions": [{
        "resource": "orders",
        "permissions": ["get", "post"]
    }]
}]
```

If permissions is empty array whole resource should be deleted.

How would I update permission on resource `orders` where role is `ops`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved this. First I fetch the entry in a loop and then I update on by one.

I know this is not a better solution using nested loops. If can be optimized, please feel free to edit.

```
const doUpdatePermissions = async (resourcePermissions) => {
  const promises = resourcePermissions.map(async (aclData) => {
    const result = await Acl.findOne({ role: aclData.role });
    aclData.resourcePermissions.forEach((passedResourcePermission) => {
      result.resourcePermissions.forEach((existingResourcePermission, index) => {
        if (passedResourcePermission.resource === existingResourcePermission.resource
            && passedResourcePermission.permissions.length === 0) {
          result.resourcePermissions.splice(index, 1);
        } else if (passedResourcePermission.resource === existingResourcePermission.resource) {
          existingResourcePermission.permissions = passedResourcePermission.permissions;
        }
      });
    });
    result.save();
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```